PUDB - unwanted output from _io.TextIOWrapper
I've just started trying out PUDB and it seems great, but it keeps printing these types of unwanted messages that overwrite the window:
2024-11-25 11:13:30,601 DEBUG Waiting for input: descriptors=[<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_UNIX, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0>, <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>], timeout=0
2024-11-25 11:13:30,601 DEBUG Input ready: [(SelectorKey(fileobj=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>, fd=0, events=1, data=None), 1)]
2024-11-25 11:13:30,601 DEBUG Decoded codes: ['down'], raw codes: [27, 91, 66]
2024-11-25 11:13:30,603 DEBUG Drawing screen with size (237, 63)

I don't get anything like this when debugging using pdb. The log level in my program is set to DEBUG, so I assume it's some DEBUG output from a module being used by PUDB.
If it helps, I'm running this using python 3 via PuTTY on Ubuntu 20; there's no XServer, so PUDB uses the terminal window rather than popping up a new window. I'm simply doing python3 -m pudb.run <myscriptname & parameters>
I've searched for answers on StackOverflow and elsewhere but not seen this kind of thing mentioned anywhere. Any suggestions on how to prevent these messages being printed to stdout?
